# How to paginate through Room database with random order?

Tags: android, pagination, android-room

So I have a list of items and I have implemented the pagination feature easily like this:

```
b.rcvItems.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            if (dy > 0) { 
                int threshold = 20;
                int count = adapter.getItemCount();
                LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
                int lastVisible = layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
                if (state != STATE_LOADING && (lastVisible >= count - threshold)) {  
                    loadItems(items.size());
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

And here I load the items:

```
 private void loadItems(int from) {
    final int COUNT = 50;
    items.addAll(new ArrayList<>(database.itemDAO().getSome(COUNT, from, true)));
    updateView();
 }
```

And here is my query:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM item ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT :count OFFSET :offset")
List<Item> getSome(int count, int offset);
```

Everything works well so far. But now I want to be able to show random items which also can be paginated. How can I get this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can achieve this in two ways:

**The First:** is by fetching all items from your Room database, shuffle the list of items, and paginate on this list.
Although, this way is not possible when you have a **large number of rows** in your database.

**The second:** is to fetch the IDs of all your rows from Room database like follows:

```
@Query("SELECT item_id FROM item")
List<Integer> getAllIDs();
```

then, shuffle the list of IDs you got, and paginate on the list of IDs like follows:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM item WHERE item_id IN (:ids)")
List<Item> getItemsWithIDs(List<Integer> ids);
```

```
// you had your shuffled IDs in allIDList
 private void loadItems(int from) {
    final int COUNT = 50;
    List<Integer> subList = allIDList.subList(from, from + COUNT)
    items.addAll(new ArrayList<>(database.itemDAO().getItemsWithIDs(subList)));
    updateView();
 }
```

**P.S** for the subList fetching I think the returned items from the database wouldn't be in the same order as in the subList of IDs, if you want to fetch the items exactly as their order in the shuffled array, I guess you need to fetch the items one by one.

Comment: That's a very nice idea. Though I would wait more to see if there is any built-in solution.

Comment: Interesting, I'm also gonna follow.